# How to set an 'int' Java model property to its original unset state rather than to zero in the App Engine datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

One of the properties of my Java model class representing a datastore entity, is represented by an int value:

```
int trackedUserId;
```

This value is set to a particular user id during the course of the app's execution. And then at other points I want to reset it to its original unset state represented by a null value. But the only way I can see to reset it is to set it to a value of zero. Is there some other way in JDO to reset a property to its unset state?

Comment: Errm, in Java an "int" is never "unset". An Integer, on the other hand, can be.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is a primitive value, so it can't be set to `null`. Per the JDO docs, [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html):

> If a datastore entity is loaded into
>   an object and doesn't have a property
>   for one of the object's fields and the
>   field's type is a nullable
>   single-value type, the field is set to
>   null. When the object is saved back to
>   the datastore, the null property
>   becomes set in the datastore to the
>   null value. If the field is not of a
>   nullable value type, loading an entity
>   without the corresponding property
>   throws an exception. This won't happen
>   if the entity was created from the
>   same JDO class used to recreate the
>   instance, but can happen if the JDO
>   class changes, or if the entity was
>   created using the low-level API
>   instead of JDO.

If you're creating a new record which has an `int` field, and don't specify a value, it will have Java's default value for such fields, which is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer trackedUserId;
trackedUserId = 1;
//voodoo happens
//so you reset to null
trackedUserId = (Integer) null;
```

Like you said, its original state is represented by a null value, so if you want it to be null again, simply set it as such.

Comment: Too bad `trackedUserId = null;` is an illegal statement in Java.

Comment: If you replace `int` with `Integer` you will be able to set it to null. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html